# Find the lowest location within rows where there are non-zero elements for each column in a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

For example, I have a 4x6 matrix A:

```
A =

     0     0     0     0     4     3
     0     2     1     0     0     0
     0     5     0     8     7     0
     8     9    10     3     0     2
```

I want to find the lowest location within the rows of A where non-zero elements are found for each column. It should go like this:

```
column 1 => row 4
column 2 => row 2 
column 3 => row 2
column 4 => row 3
column 5 => row 1
column 6 => row 1
```

And the result should look like the following vector:

```
Result = [4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]
```

Anyone has any idea how to obtain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
A = [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3;
     0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 5, 0, 8, 7, 0;
     8, 9, 10, 3, 0, 2];

indices = repmat((1:size(A))', [1, size(A, 2)]);
indices(A == 0) = NaN;
min(indices, [], 1)
```

Here indices is:

```
indices =

1   1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4   4
```

We then set every element of `indices` to `NaN` wherever A is zero, which gives us:

```
indices = 

NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     1     1
NaN     2     2   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN     3   NaN     3     3   NaN
  4     4     4     4   NaN     4
```

We then simply take the minimum of each column

Answer (score 5):

One approach to solve for a generic case -

```
[valid,idx] = max(A~=0,[],1)
out = idx.*valid
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     0     0     0     0    -4     3
     0     2     1     0     0     0
     0     5     0     8     7     0
     0     9    10     3     1     2
out =
     0     2     2     3     1     1
```

- As seen from the sample run, for a case when there are all zeros (column-1), we get output of `zero` to indicate that there are no non-zeros in that column.
- It also takes care of negative numbers (column-5).

Comment: Using the fact that `max` returns index of first occurrence of value, if there are more than one maxim. To do that you are explicitly making them all equal by masking, so that maxim is always 1 :) Bravo +1

Comment: Thank you as well. Nicely done. One more thing.. what if I want the location within rows with minimum 2 consecutive values for each column and the rest set to zeros? To consider your sample: `A =  0     0     0     0    -4     3
     0     2     1     0     0     0
     0     5     0     8     7     0
     0     9    10     3     1     2`  I would get the following: `Result =   0     2     0     3     3     0`

Comment: @Bowecho That sounds like a different problem, consider posting a new question on it?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of one combination that uses [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) and [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), I'm sure there's a better way.

With your given `A`, assuming it's an array of integers:

```
[r, c] = ind2sub(size(A), find(A ~= 0));
[~, ia, ~] = unique(c);
result = r(ia)';
```

Returns:

```
result =

     4     2     2     3     1     1
```

I did it this way because `find` returns the [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) of the array it's searching. MATLAB arrays are stored column-major in memory, so it's as if each column is stacked on top of the other. `ind2sub` converts these linear indices back to their subscripts based on the size of the original array. Then I use `unique` to find the first instance of each column and return those row numbers only.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution, using [sum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) and [cumsum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
Result = sum(cumsum(A ~= 0) == 0) + 1;
```